# Installing app on client Salesforce platform without requiring admin access?

Tags: managed-package

Our organisation has had a managed package developed to integrate our Software (a Training Management System) with Salesforce, and it is now in our hands to distribute this package.

We have documentation on the package (herein known as the Connector) and clients are able to install it themselves. However for those that are not able to install it themselves (due to complexities or time issues) they require us to install it (essentially consultancy).

My questions are,

1. What is the best way for us to install the Connector on the client platform without requiring admin/user access?
2. Our package developers recommended [Salesforce LMA](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_lma.meta/workbook_lma/), but my understanding is this is based on licenses and package versions rather than the installation of the package itself?
3. Can a package be installed without requiring admin access from a third-party?

It's a bit of a noob question, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, installing an app requires administrative privileges. If they have premier support, they could probably ask to have support install the app for them, or if they have a spare license, they could set up a user for you to use temporarily. There's no way you can just force an app into their org, even if you have the org Id.